# Multiple spawn-fcgi instances in rc.conf

Tags: freebsd, spawn-fcgi

I need to run two instances of [spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) on my FreeBSD 8.2 box - one for PHP and one for Python scripts. I can run them manually like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -- /usr/local/bin/php5-cgi
/usr/local/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001 -- /usr/local/bin/python
```

But I prefer having it enabled and configured in my **/etc/rc.conf**:

```
spawn_fcgi_enable="YES"
spawn_fcgi_app="/usr/local/bin/php5-cgi"
spawn_fcgi_bindaddr="127.0.0.1"
spawn_fcgi_bindport="9000"
```

Is it possible to enable two or more `spawn-fcgi` jobs in **/etc/rc.conf**? Do I have to create a copy of **/usr/local/etc/rc.d/spawn-fcgi** script and modify it to use slightly different param names like `spawn_fcgi2_enable`? I am curious if anyone has a working implementation because it should be a pretty common problem to solve. I am also willing to hear any other suggestions on running multiple `spawn-fcgi` instances automatically on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy the rc-script or modify it to read the parameters from rc.conf and loop over them.

Have a look at the port net/balance, I think this one uses the loop-approach. Maybe there you can copy the coding.

Comment: www/nginx also supports 'jobs'